# How to match a word that is not preceded by "=" using Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, lookbehind

I would like to extract symbols from Fortran codes in Ruby. The symbols would have the following patterns (NOTE: the variable type and attribute parts have been filtered out):

```
a = b, c(2)       ! Match result should be "a" and "c"
d(3) = [1,2, &    ! Match result should be "d"
  3]
```

The Regex that I have tried is `((?<!=)\w+(?![^\[]*\]+)(?=( |,|\(|$)))` with `lookaround` stuffs. But due to the restriction of `lookbehind`, I can not match "= *" to exclude `b`.

I used Rubular for testing. For your convenience, see [here](http://rubular.com/r/kz3Y9xKsDV).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to fake variable length look-behind in a regex flavor that does not support it.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, I have been disappointed by this constriction. As indicated by `Explosion Pills`, we can preprocess the strings first.

Comment: The other useful thing that Ruby does not support is possessive quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your regex work you can first replace all trailing whitespace after `=`

```
.gsub(/=\s+/, '=').scan(/((?<!=)\w+(?![^\[]*\]+)(?=( |,|\(|$)))/)
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing you could do is split the line in two (at the '=') and only do your regex on the left operand.

That way you don't have to write any complex regex.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But there may be several "=" in one line.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to separate your regex into 2 expressions. Regex needn't always be a one-liner.